# does the code run slower if i have a big array?

Tags: java

If i would have an array with a huge amount of elements vs one with just a few, would the code run any slower? Even if i´m just using a few of them.

let´s say that i have

```
int[] array = new int [9999999];
```

would it matter that i put in 9999999 or is it okay to do that? Because if i don´t put in a value on the array it will say "the local variable may not have been initialized". I want it to be possible to insert basically an unlimited amount of numbers in it.

Comment: `I want it to be possible to insert basically an unlimited amount of numbers in it.` Then use a [collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/). Arrays have fixed length, `List`, `Vector` and others are dynamic.

Comment: To answer your question: Yes, it does take longer. Initializing an array takes O(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

You might want a `List` instead of an array.  The former is a data structure that can expand dynamically to meet your needs; the latter requires that you pick the size before you start.

The performance will be affected by lots of other things that you'll do in your code, but I doubt that this will be one of them.  No one can tell from one line, including you.

Comment: So I have `int[] int = new int [9999999]`. And the i add numbers to it by doing `int[i]=Double.parseDouble(part[i)]` But want to make that into a list instead how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Well just try it out. If creating a too big array such as

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int []x =new int[999_999_999];
}
```

depending on your memory settings, will immediately throw an `OutOfMemoryError`.

But even if it does not throw one, it still takes time to allocate that array.

The better approach is to use a dynamic growing structure such as `List`.

But the best approach is to design your code/algorithm in such a way that you don't need to put everything into a huge array, if possible.